# How to set workspace in MoveIt

Tags: moveit, ros-noetic

guys. Is there any way to set appropriate workspace.

For example:
This is my moveit_config loaded in rviz:

[image]

and the red area has a box(in real robot) which did not show in the rviz.

well, the blue areas are the arm workspace, but, actually, in real world,
the arm just need to work at the front part of the car.

So, it there any way to set workspace and let the planner only planning in the restrict space.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware of two different ways to implement this:

1. add the obstacle(s) to your PlanningScene. The path planner should create a path that avoids collision with the object(s).
2. define Path Planner Constraints. There are various types of Constraints, but I would first look at the `PositionConstraint` to see if it fits your need. The message type associated with this feature is `moveit_msgs/Constraints`.

The only online example I have that uses Constraints is old and in c++, but I suppose it's better than nothing:

https://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html#planning-with-path-constraints

Comment: Thanks, I use the first way, which is add obstacles into scene..